# How do I insert a character at the beginning and end of each part in an imploded array?

Tags: arrays, string, format, implode

I have this...

```
$comma = implode("', " , $temp);
```

which returns this...

1680', 1667', 134', 133', 126', 83', 41', 131

I want it to return this...

'1680', '1667', '134', '133', '126', '83', '41', '131'

Answer (score 0):

this is an easy fix. Simply use

```
$comma = "'" . implode("', '",$temp) . "'";
```

which will return your imploded array with proper quoting and add the missing start and end singlequotes